# Cardview won't change my current activity (Intent won't work)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cardview

I'm creating a language app as homework for school in android.
Right now I'm setting up some clickable CardViews (which are in "LevelsHub") to take the user to another view (called "ProfileActivity") but for some reason **INTENT** is not working the way it should, it takes me back to the same view ("LevelsHub"),even though I've used it in some other parts of the app. What could be happening here?

I've followed this amazing dude tutorials on it. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUPM387qyrw and this one too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2V6Y7zQ8NU

Tried clicking on the cards itself, didn't work

I've already tried adding buttons to the card and using **Intent** on it too, didn't work.

Cycling throughout all cards to see if any of them would take me somewhere

Using this guy's method of **switch** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6CfaWW7G5Q

I've tried separating them one by one, the same result

```
package com.example.salo7.totonaku;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LevelsHub extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

 //GridLayout mainGrid;
 //CardView pronombresCard1;
 //CardView numeros1Card2;
 //CardView numeros2Card3;
 private Button  pronombresBtn1;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_levels_hub);

     //mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
     pronombresBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pronombresBtn1);
     //numeros1Btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numeros1Btn2);
     //numeros2Btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numeros2Btn3);

     //Add click listener
     pronombresBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);


     //Set Event
     //setSingleEvent (mainGrid);
     //setToggleEvent (mainGrid);
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.pronombresBtn1 : i = new Intent(LevelsHub.this, 
profileActivity.class);startActivity(i); break;
        default:break;
    }
}

/*private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //ciclar childs de mainGrid
    for (int i=0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();i++){
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == 
-1){
                    //Cambia el color

cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                    Toast.makeText(LevelsHub.this,"State: 
true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    Toast.makeText(LevelsHub.this,"State: 
false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}*/

/*private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    //ciclar childs de mainGrid
    for (int i=0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();i++){
        CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int finalI = i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(LevelsHub.this,"Cliqueado en index " + 
finalI,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (finalI == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(LevelsHub.this,"Clicado 
pronombres",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent accountIntent = new Intent(LevelsHub.this, 
profileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
 }*/
}
```

It should only take me to another view, can anyone help me out a bit?

**UPDATE**
Didn't know XML was necessary to explain my mistake, but here it is :).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".LevelsHub">
<!--android:background="@drawable/bg"-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:text="NIVELES"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <!--Row 1-->
    <!--Column 1-->

    <!--Column 2-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/pronombresCard1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logomakr_negro" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pronombres"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pronombresBtn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Empezar" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/numeros1Card2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logomakr_negro" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Números 1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/numeros1Btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Empezar" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--Row 2-->
    <!--Column 1-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/numeros2Card3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logomakr_negro" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Números 2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/numeros2Btn3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Empezar" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--Column 2-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="102dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logomakr_negro" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="¡Más niveles en camino!"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which activity do you want to open on click? Currently, you are trying to open `ProfileActivity` on click event.

Comment: Where is your XML?

Comment: have you added both activities to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry, i just left a testing parameter there, it should open ProfileActivity just for testing, I'm guessing it'll take me to my new view once it works ':)

Comment: @VasiliFedotov Yes, both are added to the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is `profileActivity` name of class, not instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically after some digging, debug and more I was able to find the answer to my problem. Which basically was that `LevelsHub` activity was correct but in my `profileActivity` activity I had a button which was not linking correctly to the `OnClickListener` I had for it, so all I did was correct that and now is working like a charm. 
Thanks to everybody who helped me out and gave some advices.

Answer (score 0):

You have code to start activity in same line, So the code after `;` will be skipped. Format your code properly and move `startActivity()` to next line.

```
case R.id.pronombresBtn1 : 
    i = new Intent(LevelsHub.this,profileActivity.class);
    startActivity(i); 
break;
```

Comment: Thank you for listing a possible solution, sadly it didn't work even though I changed it the way you said :(

Answer (score 0):

Add two properties in your **`CardView`**

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

It will work.

Feel free to comment if you get any problem.